# VSCode doesn't recognize my variable names in C source files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This issue comes out when I update my VS Code to latest version.

The editor can't recognize all variable names that I defined, and when I move the cursor to my variable (such as variable `a` in line 7: `printf("a=%d\n", a);` at my demo), it doesn't show up the definition of variable 'a' at line 5, rather, it shows something outside my source file:
[image: demo_abnormal]

The C++ form in identical environment:
[image: demo_normal]

Here is my environment:

- the only activated extension : `C/C++ v1.8.4`
- the VCS is equipped and link to remote repo
- CMake is equipped

I also discovered that my local projects (equipped with VSC, but doesn't link to remote repo) are working well, but the projects with VSC (link to remote repo) will let this issue happened.

Comment: It seems that your VSCode does interpret `.c` files as C++ source code. Do you have any related file associations set? Have a look into your settings (Files: Associations and C_Cpp: Auto Add File Associations). Also test if C_Cpp › Default › Browse: Limit Symbols To Included Headers is checked.